# How can I set the length of an input to be either 8 or 14 characters long?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
<form>
  <input pattern=".{5}|{10}">
      <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
</form>
```

It seems there must be some way of getting it to work?

edit to clarify: I do not want to allow 9,10,11,12,13. I want to just allow 8 or 14
Thanks,
nb: I am unable to use the Jquery Validation plugin because reasons.

Comment: use maxlength html attr

Comment: If it is type=number then you can use max attribute
<input type="number" min = "5" max="10"/>

Comment: Hi, yes but I do not want it to accept anything in between 5 and 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify it through the following regex pattern:

```
^.{8}$|^.{14}$
```

This is what your code would look like:

```
<form>
  <input pattern="^.{8}$|^.{14}$">
  <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
</form>
```

**Railroad Diagram:**

[image: Regex Visualization]

**Description:**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{8}                     any character except \n (8 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{14}                    any character except \n (14 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP6bQ8/2)**

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `.` after the pipe.

```
<input pattern=".{8}|.{14}">
```